# ArrayList<Enum> returns "References to generic type Enum<e> should be parameterized

Tags: java, enums

The following code:

```
  ArrayList<Enum> chgList = new ArrayList<Enum>();

  for (Iterator<Enum> eit = chgList.iterator(); eit.hasNext();) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList Enum: " + eit.next());
  }
```

Returns warnings "References to generic type Enum should be parameterized".

I need the ArrayList to return an Enumeration type.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do do go via Interator? You can directly make a foor loop in the style: for (Enum e : chgList) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my own answer and learned a valuable lesson about types.

```
public enum FieldChg {NAMECHANGED, ADDRESSCHANGED, DOBCHANGED}

public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<FieldChg> chgList = new ArrayList<FieldChg>();

for (Iterator<FieldChg> eit = chgList.iterator(); eit.hasNext();) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList Enum: " + eit.next());
}
```